# how to solve the error : await is only valid in async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am building an app in node.js ,
i want to call a async function in users.js file which is defined inside middleware/index.js file , i have defined the function in index.js and wrapped it into an object ( for some reason) and exported that object:

function defination in middleware/index.js:

```
middlewareObj.getPostsHomePage = async function(obj){
  await getPostsHomePageTrending(obj, getPostsHomePagePopular);

  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
  console.log(obj)
  return obj;
  
}
module.exports = middlewareObj;
```

users.js :

```
const middlewareObj = require("../middleware/index.js");
await  middlewareObj.getPostsHomePage(obj);
```

on running the code i am getting error:

> ```
> await getPostsHomePage(obj);
>   ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
> ```

What is the reason for this error and how can i solve it?

Comment: In users.js you are using await without being in an asynchronous function.

Comment: if this is in a nodejs module, you can use top level await - but it needs to be a module (i.e. use import/export, not module.exports/require)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` keyword can only  by used within an `async` function:

```
async function() {
   await getPostsHomePage(obj);
}
```

You can also use promises, if you don't need to use `async` function:

```
getPostsHomePage(obj).then(result => {
   console.log(result); // Do your stuff here later
})
```